designing built-ins for a small walk in closet; potential issues with depth of shelves and crown molding
Our bedroom currently has a small walk-in, about 5'x 8.5'. Right now we've got the classic contractor wire shelves, and I've decided to finally rip them out and I want to put in fully custom built-ins as a gift to my wife. Here's a quick mock-up of the design so far:
 https://imgur.com/a/l9nfaJk
I've currently designed out 20" deep shelves, with the hanger rods 11" from the back. I know 24" is ideal, but that would leave very little room for maneuvering in the closet, especially the half hidden hanger section to the right. Measuring our clothes and hangers, I think I could even get away with 10" from the back, though I know 12" is standard.
Now onto my primary issues (though I'm open to all feedback please!):
this is what the ceiling in my closet looks like:

https://imgur.com/a/xudJaPc
That sprinkler is only 22" from the back wall, and the attic access trim is right at 20 1/4". So, if I want to stick with 20" deep shelves, it throws any nice crown molding I would add out the window.
So, I'd love to hear ideas on what you all think I should do here, is this still worth pursuing? Do you think I could get away with maybe 18" deep shelves? I've also considered keeping the hanger sections at 20" deep, and the shoebox section could be shallower, but would that look terrible?
Any help or advice would be great, thank you!

Advice: closets don't need crown molding. They are a functional space.

Before you go hog-wild with the built-ins, you really should be looking hard at the NFPA 13D rules around sprinkler obstructions...storage close to sprinklers will screw up the water pattern when the head goes off.

My best advice...drop the crown moulding.
